# my action method returning {"success=true,message="work done"} ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, web, model-view-controller

Here is my create action method. I want get alert form it when success is true.

```
public JsonResult Create(Student student ,HttpPostedFileBase img)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (img !=null)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(img.FileName);
                var ext = Path.GetExtension(img.FileName);
                var filename = name + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyff") + ext;
                img.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/"+filename));
                student.ImageName = filename;
                student.Path = "~/img/" + filename;
            }
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new  { success = true, responseText = "The attached file is not supported." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

        ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(db.Classes, "Id", "Name", student.ClassID);
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { success = false, message = "data not saved" } };

    }
```

Here is my ajax function :

```
    function onsub(form) {
    $.validations.unobtrusive.parse(form);
    if (form.valid()) {
        var ajaxConfig = {
            type: "POST",
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),

            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success ) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                } else {
                    // DoSomethingElse()
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($(form).attr("enctype") == "multipart/form-data") {
            ajaxConfig["contentType"] = false;
            ajaxConfig["processData"] = false;
        }
        $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I get an alert form it 
without reloading the form. I also want to submit images and other files to create an action method.

This is the result that I get after submitting the form:

[image: result i getting after submitting form]

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are calling Create action which returning the JSON Result and the same Json response is displayed in browser.

Their should be a View page from where you will call this method by using the Ajax call, then you will be able to see your alert message.